# Floating search bar right without reversing order of inputs?

Tags: html, css, asp-classic, vbscript

I'm trying to float my search box right, however when I do that it is reversing the order of the inputs so that "search" is on the left. It should be the other way around. I know that you can just reverse the order of the elements for list items, but I tried that and it still didn't work. Here is my markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type-"text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container_12">


            <h1 class="grid_12">Overhaulers</h1>

            <div class="navigation grid_5">

            <nav>

                <a href="default.asp">Home</a> 
                <a href="insert.asp">Insert</a>
                <a href="delete.asp">Delete</a>
                <a href="edit.asp">Edit</a>

                <%

                if Session("username")="" then
                Response.write("<a href=""login.asp"">Login </a>")
                else 
                Response.write("<a href=""logout.asp"">Logout </a>")
                dim greetingName
                greetingName = Session("username")
                response.write "Hello " + greetingName + "!"
                end if

                response.write "</div>"

                response.write "<div class=""grid_5 prefix_2"">"&_
                "<form id=""search""action=""results.asp"" method=""get"">" &_
                "<input type=""hidden"" name=""stage"" value=""2"">"&_
                "<input type=""text"" id=""search"" name=""search"">" &_
                "<input id=""searchsubmit""type=""submit"" value=""Search"">" &_
                "</form>"&_
                "</div>"



                %>




            </nav>



    </body>
```

And my styling:

```
#search {
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
#search {
    float:right;
}

#search input {
    float:left;
}
```